# LDAP Failure with Zend/Apache

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2, ldap

I have a very simple php ldap script that is only failing when running with Zend and Apache.  When I run this script from the command line, it passes.  Running strace, I can see where the behavior changes, but I cannot tell why.  I have confirmed that the same ldap.conf is being read and the same ldap.so is being loaded.

I believe this is because of a certificate problem, but my settings are supposed to ignore certificate issues.

Version Information (these appear to be identical between running from php and apache):

```
OpenSSL:   0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
OpenLdap:  $Id: ldap.c 313665 2011-07-25 11:42:53Z felipe $
Zend:      5.5
PHP:       5.3.8


<?php
      ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
      putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
      $ds = ldap_connect("ldaps://myserver.com:636");
      $db = ldap_bind($ds, 'user', 'pass');
?>
```

In my ldap.conf, I have only  "TLS_REQCERT never".  I realize that this is duplicated above.

When running under apache, I get the following trace from ldap:

```
ldap_create 
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://myserver.com:636)
ldap_bind_s 
ldap_simple_bind_s 
ldap_sasl_bind_s 
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request 
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection 
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP myserver.com:636 
ldap_new_socket: 20 
ldap_prepare_socket: 20
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying <myip>:636 
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 20 tm: -1 async: 0 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A 
TLS certificate verification: depth: 0, err: 20, subject: /CN=mycn.com,
    issuer: /CN=Collaboration Services CA 
TLS certificate verification: Error, unable to get local issuer certificate 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A 
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 write finished A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 write finished A 
TLS: can't connect: error:140D308A:SSL routines:TLS1_SETUP_KEY_BLOCK:cipher or hash unavailable. 
ldap_err2string
```

When running the same script using the same php executable on the command line I get:

```
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://myserver.com:636)
ldap_bind_s
ldap_simple_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP myserver.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying <my ip>:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
TLS certificate verification: depth: 0, err: 20, subject: /CN=myserver.com, issuer: /CN=Collaboration Services CA
TLS certificate verification: Error, unable to get local issuer certificate
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
```

Comment: What you are seeing there is a problem with OpenSSL. Compare the OpenSSL information shown by `phpinfo()` with that shown by `php -i` and I suspect you will see different information - possibly because of different ini files, or possibly the PHP/OpenSSL version in use in the terminal is completely different to that of Apache. If you edit the question with the respective LDAP and OpenSSL-related output of the above commands, we can take a look at the potential causes/solutions...

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested and I cannot find any differences.  Same ini files, same versions of openssl(OpenSSL 0.9.8o ), ldap, php, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this when inspecting results from running strace showed that it did not have permission to open my ldap.conf file.  Opening permissions fixed the issue.  However, the file is not supposed to be needed since it only had the same setting from the environment variable:

putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');